# Как удалить или пропустить несколько пустых новых строк в переменной?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
   text VARCHAR2(4000) := 'line 1 text text text text text text text, 
line 2 text text text text text text text, 
  
  
   
line 3 text text text text text text text.';
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line (text);
END;
/
```

Желаемый результат:

```
line 1 text text text text text text text, 
line 2 text text text text text text text, 
line 3 text text text text text text text.
```

Пытаюсь удалить все пустые строки из переменной. Пробовал использовать `regexp_replace`, но не смог получить желаемого результата.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to remove or skip the multiple new line in string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63383910) от участника [@S_sauden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8153866/s-sauden)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/63383910

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Спасибо! Опять забыл :(( Удалите свой комментарий, а то с ассоциацией вроде первым должен быть.

Answer (score 2):

Хотя конечно можно использовать `^\s*$` с модификатором `m`, но самый простой способ, заменить повторяющиеся переводы строк `chr(10)`:

```
declare
    text varchar2 (4000) := '
line 1 text text text text text text text, 
line 2 text text text text text text text,


line 3 text text text text text text text.';
begin
    dbms_output.put_line (
        trim (both chr(10) from regexp_replace (
            text, chr(10)||'(\s*'||chr(10)||')+', chr(10))));
end;
/
```

Здесь `\s*` только для того, чтобы удалить строки, содержащие только пробелы.
Результат:

```
line 1 text text text text text text text, 
line 2 text text text text text text text,
line 3 text text text text text text text.
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63385084) от участника [@Sayan Malakshinov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/429100/sayan-malakshinov)</sub>